# Wanting Chrome Remote Desktop to stay connected when program closed

Tags: google-chrome, desktop, remote

I have been using Chrome Remote Desktop for a few years, everything worked fine, then suddenly it only works when the program is opened on the host computer meaning this window is open:

[image: screenshot]

This never had been the case before. I didn’t have to have Chrome opened at all and I could still connect.

While this sounds easy to fix and just simply have this opened to connect all the time. I don’t want to do this for a reason… Does anyone know how to have connect without this being opened and have it like it used to be?  I didn’t change anything on my computers to have this change either…